# How to add item status for an order in magento 2

Tags: magento2, order-status, items, status, order-items

I have multiple items in my order. How can I add item status and its tracking information for that order in `My Account` Orders?

I am using this to get orders

```
$_orders = $block->getOrders();
```

And for order status I do

```
$_order->getStatusLabel();
```

How to get the `item status` and its tracking information.

[image]

Like I have to show the

1) `item status` which I have hardcoded right now as `Shipped` and

2)  `item tracking` information.

I have found `Item.php` which have this function

```
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->getStatusName($this->getStatusId());
}
```

Is this php class ?
How can I call this function in my phtml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the status of each individual item using the following:

```
foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    echo $item->getStatus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
$_order->getStatusLabel();
```

to

```
$_order->getStatus();
```

Comment: is $_order->getStatus() for item status ?

Comment: @summu, Two items are from same order? try above code and check once, what you are getting?

Comment: yes and i need status for both items as well, item level status

Comment: I am getting order status on both item level status.

Comment: @summu, is it fine or issue?

Comment: is it an issue, the item can have a different status, like on the first-day 1st item has been shipped and on the next day 2nd item, so status would be different for both item on the first day. i.e, every item can have different status depending on the availability of items